# Direct3D 9Ex - Creating a Full Screen Device

Tags: c++, fullscreen, directx-9

I've looked all over the internet for this and found nothing.

I know that Direct3D 9Ex works after Alt-Tabbing out of the program, unline Direct3D 9 (which just crashes). For that reason, I am trying to use Direct3D 9Ex. I want to make the program fullscreen. However, whenever I perform any operation with the device (IDirect3DDevice9Ex*) I get an access violation reading memory location 0x00000000. This is my code:

```
Direct3DCreate9Ex(D3D_SDK_VERSION, &pD3D);
ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = iHeight;
d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = iWidth;
d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
d3dpp.Windowed = false;
D3DDISPLAYMODEEX dm;
dm.Format = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
dm.Height = iHeight;
dm.Size = sizeof(dm);
dm.RefreshRate = 60;
dm.ScanLineOrdering = D3DSCANLINEORDERING_PROGRESSIVE;
dm.Width = iWidth;
pD3D->CreateDeviceEx(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &dm, &pD3DDevice);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have not checked that pD3D is not null.  The call on the first line might be failing.

Comment: It can't be null, considering that the call to CreateDeviceEx is not throwing an access violation.

Comment: Besides, I checked and it wasn't failing.

Comment: @bojoradarial: As a side note and AFAIK, D3D9 doesn't just crash after Alt+Tabbing. You just need to handle "device lost" events and your resources correctly.

Comment: You stated that you were getting an access violation.  It wasn't clear that that was not on the CreateDeviceEx Line. :)

Comment: So, to make sure I understand, the code you've posted is fine, but the code you haven't posted is crashing and you'd like us to guess why?

Comment: The code I haven't posted that causes the crash is `pD3DDevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);`

Comment: And you're positive `pD3DDevice` is not `NULL`?  It would help to see a short complete example of the issue.

Comment: @yzt You said you just need to handle device lost events in D3D9. That is another option; I'm only using D3D9EX because I've tried for ages and have had no success. If you can explain how to do it with D3D9, that would help.

Comment: I guarantee that pD3DDevice isn't null - I tested it (`if (pD3DDevice == NULL) MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to create device", "Error", MB_OK);`). The message box doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

`d3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz (0)` differs from `dm.RefreshRate (60)`.
They should both be set to the same rate, try `D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT` for both.

The `HRESULT` return from the `CreateDeviceEx` call should be checked using the `SUCCEEDED` or `FAILED` macro.